# Difficult differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, someone challenged me to solve a differential equation, and this would be unorthodox, but MSE I need your help. It turned out impossible to solve by the methods I know. I would prefer hints over solutions.

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d}x} +k(k+1)y=0$$

Comment: “impossible to solve by the methods I know” What methods do you know?

Comment: Linear homogenous method, laplace transform, exact D.E.s, separable D.Es, variation of parameters, undetermined coefficients, integrating factor, direct integration. These came up. Maybe forgot some.

Comment: Hint: Wolfram alpha has the solution, which is elementary. Could give you a hint as to the sort of thing to do ;)

Comment: I don't wanna wolframalpha it or see the solution. Good to know that it is elementary though. Also, forgot the insertion of a new variable to collapse the D.E. into a D.E. that's solvable by the methods above.

Comment: Well, try a substitution $y=f(u)$ where $u$ is a function of $x$ (and solve for $u$ of course) - pick the right $f$ and you should be able to proceed smoothly.

Comment: use Taylor series of your function and implement that in equation and then obtain coefficients.

Comment: @Panda Totally not necessary or useful...

Comment: @Shakespear I find no right $f$, everything in this D.E. throws me off. There is always a problem.

Comment: One more hint: to choose $f$, eliminate what is nastiest here. That $\sin$ on the denominator

Comment: @Panda I got $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1) a_n x^{n-2} + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n x^{n-1} +k(k+1) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$ Any clues on how this is easier and how to proceed?

Comment: $y$ is a function of $cos(x)$... (i.e. $f=\cos$)

Comment: I thought of $-\cos$ to be honest, but it gets me nowhere. Care to show me your work?

Comment: Oh gosh, I'm sorry, these things happen late at night - I meant $y=f(\cos x)$... I.e. we make the substitution $u=\cos x$ and solve for $y$ in terms of $u$

Comment: Trust me, stick with it, even if it looks messier at first

Answer (score 1):

Let $t= -\cos x$ to transform into a well-known form in terms of $t$.